# split and create an array from a json object in js

Tags: javascript

I have a given [exif of an image](https://gist.github.com/guinslym/bf0fd7a21f2f75ff68b2) I would like to split each key of a json object and create a sorted array with it. The output I'm expecting is

```
{
  "APP14":[
    {"APP14Flags0": 16384},
    {"APP14Flags1": 0},
    {"ColorTransform": 1}
  ],
  "Composite":[
    {"Aperture": 2.8}
    {"CircleOfConfusion": 0.0309526315549036}
    {"DateTimeCreated":  "2013:08:04 13:15:03+00:00"}
    {"FocalLength35efl": 97.0717484087605}
    {"..."}
  ],
  "SourceFile": "c.jpg",
  "XMP":[
    {"AlreadyApplied": true},
    {"ApproximateFocusDistance": 1.17},
    {"AutoLateralCA": 0},
    {"Blacks2012": 0}
  ]
}
```

My last console.log({key:values}); is giving me back the same array. [js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gdiamond/L9a9h5m3/2/)

```
var the_keys =[];
_.forEach(data, function(n, key) {
  //creating an array of Uniq keys
  if(key.indexOf(':')> -1) {
    if (_.includes(the_keys, key.split(':')[0] ) == false) {
      the_keys.push(key.split(':')[0]); 
    }
  } else {
    the_keys.push(key);
  }
});

console.log(the_keys);

_.forEach(the_keys, function(key) {
  var values = []
  _.forEach(data, function(k, n) {
    if ((_.includes(the_keys, key.split(':')[0] ) ) || k == key) {
      values.push(k);
    }
  });

  console.log({key:values});
});
```

I'm splitting each keys cause I would like to create an HTML table like for this [exif viewer site](http://regex.info/exif.cgi)

Comment: Hi Tushar! from my gist my expected output is like I described in the first part of my questions `{
  "APP14":[
      {"APP14Flags0": 16384},
      {"APP14Flags1": 0},
      {"ColorTransform": 1}
  ],`

Comment: For the desired output ... the new javascript object is enough,  no need to create the table [gist](https://jsfiddle.net/gdiamond/L9a9h5m3/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/L9a9h5m3/3/

Give this a look. Its basically splitting up the key and then building the object piece by piece. For the last token its assigning the value

```
_.forEach(data, function(v, k){
    kParts = k.split(':');

    var lastObj = returnObj;
    for(var i=0; i<kParts.length - 1; i++){
       var kPart = kParts[i]
       if(!lastObj.hasOwnProperty(kPart)) lastObj[kPart] = {}
       lastObj = lastObj[kPart];
   }

   lastObj[kParts[kParts.length - 1]] = v;

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/L9a9h5m3/3/